# Inserting exported PHP array from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have exported data from my MySQL database in PHP My Admin. I exported it as a PHP Array.

```
$measurements = array(
  array('measurement_id' => '1','measurement_name' => 'bag','measurement_last_updated' => '2018-01-03 14:40:49'),
  array('measurement_id' => '2','measurement_name' => 'bowl','measurement_last_updated' => '2018-01-03 14:40:49'),
  array('measurement_id' => '3','measurement_name' => 'box','measurement_last_updated' => '2018-01-03 14:40:49'),
  array('measurement_id' => '4','measurement_name' => 'handful','measurement_last_updated' => '2018-01-03 14:40:49'),
  array('measurement_id' => '5','measurement_name' => 'package','measurement_last_updated' => '2018-01-03 14:40:49'),
  array('measurement_id' => '6','measurement_name' => 'piece','measurement_last_updated' => '2018-01-03 14:40:49'),
  array('measurement_id' => '7','measurement_name' => 'pizza','measurement_last_updated' => '2018-01-03 14:40:49'),
  array('measurement_id' => '8','measurement_name' => 'slice','measurement_last_updated' => '2018-01-03 14:40:49'),
  array('measurement_id' => '9','measurement_name' => 'spoon','measurement_last_updated' => '2018-01-03 14:40:49'),
  array('measurement_id' => '10','measurement_name' => 'teaspoon','measurement_last_updated' => '2018-01-03 14:40:49'),
  array('measurement_id' => '11','measurement_name' => 'tablespoon','measurement_last_updated' => '2018-01-03 14:40:49')
);
```

How can I insert this into a database again?

This is what I have tried:

```
$array_size = sizeof($measurements);
for($x=0;$x<$array_size;$x++){
            $temp = $measurements[$x];
            print_r($temp);
}
```

Comment: Where did you read that `print_r` would insert an array into your database?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to store arrays in your database, as this information will be much harder to filter, search, use, and various other reasons.

Comment: You'll have to write the code to insert each array as a new row, with each subarray as a column within that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are set on using that structure, I would do something like:

```
foreach($measurements as $v){
  functionForInsertingRows($v)
}
```

then in another function:

```
functionForInsertingRows($aInc){
  update tableName set 
  measurement_name = $aInc["measurement_name"],
  measurement_last_updated = $aInc["measurement_last_updated"]
  where measurement_id = $aInc["measurement_id"]
}
```

do note: this is psuedo code, but that is the idea I would use.  The insert or update function would use whatever technique you like to making the database changes.